# how to retain TableViewCell colour while toggling controllers in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit-state-preservation

I have created StoryBoard segue application containing 1st CategoryViewController and 2nd CheckListTableController. Category(buttons) wise I am opening different question list on tableview of CheckListTableController.

I have set check and uncheck button and its respective colour in tableView cell. I have taken NSMutableArray and adding indexPath to this to set the particular colour to cell.

When I am navigating between these controller I want my tableView cell colour should be reserve.

Any Idea how to do this. Thanks in advance.

**Edited with query 26Aug13**

Now I need same functionality by using plist file or Core data. So that user can save sessions of task and access it later. Eg. in session one he did check uncheck mark for ABC building then session saved. Session two again he did check/unchk activity for different location XYZ building then saved.

Which method would be suitable here. Plist file or Core data? Can you redirect me to specific solution.

**Edit with some Code**

```
Catergory_ViewController.m 

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender

{
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"chkListTable"])
{
     NSString *bldgArrayString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"bldg"];
    checkListTableViewController *chk= segue.destinationViewController;

    chk.gotquestArrayString = bldgArrayString;   

}
}



checkListTableViewController.m 


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
if ([gotquestArrayString isEqual:@"bldg"])
{

    buildingQuest = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Motor vehicles are not  parked in the space",

                     @"Lightning protection system (Electronic)",

                     @"Lightning protection systems available on all buildings",

                     @"Reception facilities in order and not damaged",
}
}
 //tableView button method where indexPath added to MutableArray
-(void)yesAction:(id)sender
{
arrayCheckUnchek = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)button.superview.superview;
UITableView *curTableView = (UITableView *)cell.superview;
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [curTableView indexPathForCell:cell];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[arrayCheckUnchek addObject:indexPath];
}

- (void)tableView: (UITableView*)tableView
 willDisplayCell: (UITableViewCell*)cell
forRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
// UITableViewCell *Cell = [myChklist cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
 if ([arrayCheckUnchek containsObject:indexPath])
 {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
 }
 }
```

Comment: when you loading the table view put condition and change the cell background color based on that array.

Comment: I have put some code. Could you please check.

Comment: what happend when you tried like this?

Comment: Are you talking about I should write this condition in ViewDieload if ([arrayCheckUnchek containsObject:indexPath]). It is not giving desire result. not working:(

Comment: keep this condition on cellForRowAtIndex mathod and relaod the tableview when you come to that view.

Comment: nothing happening. this logic is also not working:(. I hope You got my question.. and required answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.you need to save your NSMutable Array in Plist file or in UserDefaluts whenever you have changed the selection(checked/ unchecked) at that time you should update your Plist or userdefaluts
2.Read your plist file in ViewWillApper method in your tableviewcontroller. and pass this data to your "arraycheckuncheck"

hope it will work for you

happy icoding ....

- NSAnant

Comment: I got your point of using UserDefaults. But what would be my code in ViewDidLoad after saving just an array, how do I retrieve cell colours ?

Comment: you should create an Array of Dictionary,so you can save any number of data/property for a single cell , means Color, cell's data, cell ischeked or not,cell type, etc,
and use this in your cellForRow Datasource method of your tableview 
[array objectAtindex:indexpath.row];
[mutableDict objectForKey:@"Color"];
And you don't need to write any code in ViewDidLoad method , i'll suggest you to write your code in ViewWillApper method and simply reload your table view

Comment: Hi NSAnant. I have new query on this function can you check my new updated question with date specified above. Thanks in advance.